# how to use clientscript in module

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, module, clientscript

I want to use clientscript coding in module, then call it from a page.
dose anybody know about it?

module A

```
Module A
 public class sample
    Public Shared page As New Page
    Public Shared ClientScript As ClientScriptManager = page.ClientScript
    Public Shared Sub test()
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "test", "alert('test')", True)
    End Sub
 end class
End Module
```

page B

```
Public Class sanplepage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call A.sample.test()
    end sub
end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from this:

***Module:***

```
Module Module1

    Public Sub initTest(ByVal callerPage As Page)
        Dim scriptBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        scriptBuilder.Append("<script type='text/javascript'> ")
        scriptBuilder.Append("function clickByModule(){alert('heyyyyyyy coso, ma come si legge il tuo nome???');} ")
        scriptBuilder.Append("</script> ")
        callerPage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(callerPage.GetType(), "test", scriptBuilder.ToString)
    End Sub

End Module
```

***WebForm back-end:***

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub WebForm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Module1.initTest(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

***WebForm front-end:***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="clickByModule();" />
    </div>
</form>
```